# Angular App won't run after Cloning from a Git Repository

Tags: angular, git, npm

I recently completed the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial (with some slight modifications) and it all works fantastically well. I then wanted to try push it up to a GIT repo in VSTS, and then clone it to another machine and run it from there. Unfortunately now I've cloned it to the new machine I'm unable to get it running. Both ng serve --open and ng build fail.

Originally it was complaining about missing "@angular-devkit/build-angular" so I went ahead and installed that, unfortunately on the next build attempt there was another issue

"Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer'"

Is it going to be the case that I need to reinstall every dependency every time I clone a solution using Angular or Node, or is there a simple command I'm missing here?

Google suggested I try "npm install -g npm-install-missing" and "npm rebuild", unfortunately neither helped.

Comment: Make sure you have @angular/cli installed globally. 

Did you do an `npm i` after cloning the repo? Do it to install the modules first if not already done.

Comment: Whilst npm i went away and seemingly installed quite a few packages, the error remains when i do a build unfortunately. I have @angular/cli installed globally, however it's a different version 6.15 globally compared to 6.05 locally, could that cause issues?

Comment: It could be a reason. There are always incompatibility issues when there's even a slight version mismatch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try bring them in line

Comment: Do you have the foler "node-moudles" on your repository?

Comment: No I don't, by default it wasn't committed, and I read online that is was best practise not to, would you say thats not the case?

Comment: It's really best practice not to add it, to build th web you must to run `npm install` in the folder where the `package.json` exist.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. I'm going to try clone again and try npm install a fresh.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After cloning the project just follow the instructions.

```
cd 'your project name...'
```

And then install the packages and dependencies.

```
npm install
```

and then you can run the project by running this code.

```
ng serve
```

This should work fine.

Comment: It does yep! I'd confused it by putting the project inside an existing workspace.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `npm install` before serving

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and It got resolved using the below written method

1. Type this command in your cmd: `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. Clone your repository
3. Run `npm install` and `npm update`
4. Run `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like it was caused as I cloned my project to a sub folder of my VS workspace instead of the root. Once I cleared out the entire folder, recloned at the root, and then run npm install, everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

on your terminal make sure you are on the cloned project directory. if not cd into it

```
cd <project-name>
```

then install the packages used by running this command on your terminal;

```
npm install
```

after successful install you can now serve by running;

```
ng s --o
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to your Project folder -

```
cd c:/MYProjectFolder
```

install packages by running -

```
npm install
```

finally -

```
ng serve --o
```